# Cambiar ruta Host,Accion y controlador MVC

Tags: mvc, url

espero sea una buena pregunta.
Deseo ocultar o cambiar como se ve la URL de las acciones y controlador.

Es posible?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo deseo que se vea asi:

http://miweb.com.uy/Usuarios

http://miweb.com.uy/Account/Usuarios
Algo asi

Comment: Tu pregunta no esta clara. Puedes dar mas detalles de lo que esperas?

Comment: Estoy con @Einer, tu pregunta no es clara.¿Que es lo que quieres modificar? ¿La ruta Absoluta? ¿La ruta raiz?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que estas usando IIS express, para editar localhost por otro nombre localmente,  si es posible.

-- Visual studio

- En visual studio (modo Admin) en propiedades del proyecto web esta la propiedad
  Project url http:localhost:52035 --el valor del puerto varia dependiendo del proyecto.

  - remplazalo por http://myweb.com.uy:52035, dale check a Override application root URL.
  - dale click al boton de crear directorio virtual

--IIS express

- IIs express tiene una carpeta con las configuraciondes de los proyectos que se ejecutan

> %USERPROFILE%\My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

busca el sitio con el numero de puerto y renombra con el nombre de tu sitio asignado

```
   <site name="myweb.com.uy" id="2">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\**usernameHere**\PathToProjectHere" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52035:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
```

Antes de guardas los cambios crea una copia de la configuracion por cualquier problema

Guarda y ejecuta la aplicacion.

Nota: antes verifica que tu iisexpress este detenido,que no aparezca el icono de IIS expres en parte derecha de la pantalla windows.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Si no me equivoco es en RouteConfig del proyecto donde puedes modificar tu URL.